# How to succinctly map Map to Map

Tags: scala, scala-collections

"map map to map", what a mouthful.

Anyway, I can do:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3)
val list2 = list map (item => item + 1)
println(list2)
// List(2, 3, 4)
```

Why does the following not work?:

```
val ages = Map("alice" -> 21, "bob" -> 22)
val ages2 = ages map ((name, age) => (name, age + 1))
```

, and how do I go about making it work?

EDIT:
I figured out that I had to do:

```
val ages2 = ages map {case (name, age) => (name, age + 1)}
```

, but that doesn't answer my first question, which is why my naive first approach does not work.

Comment: I know this is not the question, but if you do not need to change the key part of your `Map`, you may also use the `mapValues` method that (lazily) applies a function on the values. Eg, here, you could do `ages2.mapValues(_ + 1)`.

Comment: Including the error message would have been a good idea. It may also have pointed you in the right direction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because the Scala compiler doesn't automatically decompose the `Tuple2` (which is the type of the key value pairs) in your `Map`.

This would work:

```
val ages2 = ages.map(pair => (pair._1, pair._2 + 1))
```

As it uses the tuple argument as a whole.

As you've noticed, using partial function syntax also works and allows you to automatically decompose the tuple:

```
val ages2 = ages map { case (name, age) => (name, age + 1) }
```

This is currently a *limitation* of the compiler. With dotty (the new new Scala compiler), this will be provided out of the box.